# Conditional watchpoint on NXP LPC55S28

Tags: c, debugging, arm, cortex-m

I need to debug a program that sets a specific memory location to 0 unexpectedly while running, leading to a hardfault down the line. I want to catch that memory write with a conditional watchpoint.

Sadly, as others have noted in existing questions, it seems like the debugging tools (OpenOCD or pyOCD) do not implement the support for conditional watchpoints: when a watchpoint is set with a condition, it will break regardless if the condition is true or false.

The remaining solution is to do this manually using the CPU registers directly. **However, I can't find a straightforward way to achieve it.** What complicates things is that the CPU features depend on the implementation, so if I'm understanding correctly, some MCU would support it whereas others potentially don't. (I may be wrong, but that's what I'm understanding by skimming through the Armv8-M Architecture Manual).

It tried a basic approach based on what I could find online:

```
DCB->DHCSR |= DCB_DHCSR_C_DEBUGEN_Msk;
DCB->DEMCR |= DCB_DEMCR_TRCENA_Msk | DCB_DEMCR_MON_EN_Msk | DCB_DEMCR_UMON_EN_Msk;

DWT->COMP2 = 0x2000CE58;
DWT->FUNCTION2 = 0;
DWT->COMP1 = (uint32_t)&void_var;
DWT->FUNCTION1 = 0x20B06;
```

But it doesn't work. I would expect the program to break when memory at 0x2000CE58 gets written to 0. I also tried setting COMP1 = 0 to no avail (not sure if it takes an address or a value).

Resources are pretty limited around this, at this point any input would help.